# Unit testing promise based code in node.js express route/controller

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, promise, bluebird

Recently I switched from using callbacks to using promise in my rest api express app. 
But I'm having trouble with unit testing routes/controller with async behaviour of the promise. Here is the sample code that needs to be unit tested.

```
var handler =  function (req, res, next) {
  var query = {}, 
  var options = {
    sort: { updatedAt: -1 },
    limit: 10
  };
  if (req.query.before) {
    query.updatedAt = { $lt: req.query.before };
  }
  // User.findAsync returns bluebird promise
  User.findAsync(query, null, options).then(function (user) {
    res.json(user);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    next(e);
  });
}
router.get('/api/users', handler);
```

My approach to test above code was to spy on req, next, and User.findAsync and check if they are called with correct arguments. But because of async behaviour of the promise, I was having trouble to check if res.json or next are get called.

I've tried to stub findAsync to return resolved promise (Promise.resolve(user)). but still then callback is executed asynchronously.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track for testing express application.

What is good strategy to test this kind of code in good separation?

I've also heard about using supertest. 
But for me, Using supertest to test from http end point feels like more of integration testing which is not unit testing and is quite expensive.

Also, In general, I would like to know if it is good practice to try to cover all of the code with unit testing (models, controller, middleware, etc) and what's good strategies or techniques of doing that. Or If it is just good enough to test http end points with super test.

Comment: what test framework are you using? Mocha has good support async testing (and I think it can be used without too much difficulty with promises). maybe you could post your test case?

Comment: I'm using mocha as test framework with sinon. I don't have trouble with unit testing a function that returns promise but my route/controller function doesn't return promise it just calls res.json or next inside then callback. This is the point where I have difficulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method being tested doesn't return a promise then you can't use the promise syntax in Mocha. You can test your method the same way you'd test any other asynchronous method - with `done` as a parameter of `it`. Let's say we want to test your `handler` function:

```
var handler =  function (req, res, next) {
  //...
  User.findAsync(query, null, options).then(function (user) {
    res.json(user);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    next(e);
  });
}
```

We can write a test as such:

```
describe("The handler", function(){
     it("calls res.json", function(done){ // note the done argument
         handler({query: {before: 5}, // mock request
                 {json: done} // res.json calls our `done` param of this function
                 function(){ throw new Error("error called"); });
     });
});
```

Note that we mocked the request, response and the `next` handler. Our mocked response has a json method that lets the test know it is complete (this can be a function if you want to make assertions inside it) and if `next` is called instead we throw to signal it's not something that was supposed to happen.